# Array operations in Matlab with different array sizes: different behavior depending on the Matlab version?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Sorry if this has been asked before, I'm new to the site and tried looking for a similar question but couldn't find anything on the site or in the MATLAB docs.

So I have the following MWE:

```
a = ones(5,3);
b = ones(5,1);
a == b
a ./ b
```

If I run this in my laptop using Matlab R2018a, the operation goes through with the following results:

```
ans =

  5×3 logical array

   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1

ans =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
```

So basically it will interpret the second array as a column vector and compare/divide the elements of each column in the first matrix with/by the corresponding elements of the column vector.

However, if you run this exact same code on version R2015b (version I have in a separate workstation) it throws the following error:

> Error using ==
>
> Matrix dimensions must agree.

And a similar one for `./`

Does this mean the behavior of basic math operations for arrays was changed in one of the latest versions of Matlab? I haven't been able to locate such a change in the docs. Is there any way to get the behavior of the first example on older versions?

Comment: Since 2016b Matlab supports implicit expansion, as explained in [this](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) article by Loren. In the link you will find possible solutions as to how you can obtain the same behaviour for versions earlier than 2016b.

Comment: @pkpkpk Thanks man! I didn't think of the term 'implicit expansion' :D That link and the _repmat_ function indeed solve the issue.

Comment: You are welcome :) You might also find interesting her second blog post about it [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/11/10/more_thoughts_about_implicit_expansion/).

Comment: Nice, that's pretty interesting. I like the addition myself, although I guess I can understand the concerns from some users.

Comment: @Jax: don't use `rempat`, use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour changed in R2016b. See this blog post for details: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

There is no way to get the same implicit expansion behaviour in older versions, although you can use `bsxfun` to get explicit expansion.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer adds additional information when compared to my comment above. Also what do you mean by *there is no way to get the same behaviour* ? In that post Loren does explain how you can obtain the same behaviour in previous version.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry, I wasn’t clear enough in my answer. Edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: @pkpkpk My apologies, I didn’t see your comment before posting my answer. If you have an answer, though, it’s best to post it as answer rather than as a comment, as it makes it easier for others to search for and find.

Comment: Not a problem, and I do agree with you, however I was hoping someone would answer providing clear examples of how implicit expansion can be achieved with `bsxfun`. While Loren's post is indeed very informative, perhaps its a good idea to add her snippets of code to the answer. If, for some reason, (very unlikely I agree) that blog post became unavailable, the answer as it is wouldn't be very useful.